# How do we test a hypothesis of a specific number from a regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have a homework assignment that has regression results that may or may not make sense.

There are 3 variables: price, bathrooms, and bedrooms.

Doing a univariate regression of bathrooms and bedrooms separately on price.

The price is negative when it's being run with bedrooms. It's not clear if the results are supposed to make sense so I'm not too worried about any biases. I can address those.

My question is, I have some p-value of 0.00.

But what exactly is my hypothesis here? The normal is that the null hypothesis is if there is any change. That's not what I'm worried about.

I'm worried about whether I can reject a null that says the coefficient for bedroom should be negative.

I hope this makes sense. I just want to test a hypothesis on whether the coefficient is equal to some negative number and if, and how, that will change my p-value.

Please ask questions if that wasn't clear.

Comment: When you say the price is negative do you mean the coefficient is negative or the predicted price?

Comment: @mdewey the coefficient is negative.

Comment: Well that means that the more bedrooms it has the less it costs. That seems rather implausible to me so I would go back to the people who gave me the data and ask them to clarify.